# SPGridView multi column filter issue

Tags: filter, spgridview

I have taken SPGridView Control and kept allow filtering as true.
But I am not able to filter on more than one column.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Here is your answer http://sadomovalex.blogspot.in/2011/03/spgridview-with-filtering-by-multiple.html or you may share details of the error if already tried that.

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Multi-Column-Filter-and-6765a863

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want the filter where, Firstly I filter col1 and then filter on col2, then my filter should preserve the value of both the columns. The above link  is something related to TaxonomyFieldMulti. i.e Multi values. But I want multi columns